# How can I pass a parameter for gem installation when I run bundle install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I added the [**pg gem**](http://rubygems.org/gems/pg) to my gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

When I run `bundle install`, I get this error:

```
Installing pg (0.10.1) with native extensions /Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/Users/benhartney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

It seems I need to pass in this config parameter

```
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
```

How can I do this when I use `bundle install`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to set a build config option like so:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
```

More info can be found in the [bundle config command documentation](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-config.1.html)

Comment: Awesome!  Looks like this stores it in the config and will be used in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Run 'bundle config' before 'bundle install' to set the parameters, i.e.:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
bundle install
```

Answer (score 9):

with **Rails3** and **PostgreSQL**. I do like this

```
>rails new test_app -d postgreSQL
>cd test_app
>mkdir .bundle
>echo "BUNDLE_BUILD__PG: --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config" > .bundle/config
>bundle install
```

so you can keep config in source control.

*for user's profile*

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config
```

this will create ~/.bundle/config file.

Comment: Unless it's only you working on the app and every place it may run has the same path to the postgres config, you shouldn't check this kind of thing into your scm. It is environment-specific, and might not be the same for every machine. That's why, generally, it's best to do it per-user.

Comment: Idlefingers, yes. that's right. so that why i gave two options. your/his choice, what best for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The damn problem almost killed me, fortunately, I fixed.

You can

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
```

my path is `ARCHFLAGS="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin/pg_config`

Here is the guarantee you installed the pg

you have to make sure your command "bundle install" goes here as well. especially, if you have multiple pg versions.

so we have to set the bundle config before bundle

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/pathbin/pg_config
```

summary:

```
$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin/pg_config
$ bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config
$ bundle install
`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby 2.x and up, then thrift 0.9.0 can't build with it. see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2219. Thrift 0.9.2 is fixed.

Try installing:
`gem install rbhive -v 1.0.3.pre`