# RVM doesn't recognize installed gem, so bundle install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

`Bundle install` command fails because `gem install pg` fails:

```
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds
```

I can though, install pg with certain options:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-9.3/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-9.3
```

Still.. running `bundle install` fails, saying:

```
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds
```

Well ye I know it fails, that why I installed it before, with options given,
How do I make the bundle see it the gem is already installed.? (or maybe make the bundle command to run `gem install pg -- --with-pg-include`  instead of `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` so it will succeed)

I also use rvm, and i'm rather clueless about it, so maybe even though I the pg gem is installed:

```
gem list pg
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
pg (0.17.1)
```

The application doesn't recognized the installed pg gem? if so How do I make the application's rvm see that the required gem is already installed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found answer: [How can I pass a parameter for gem installation when I run bundle install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167829/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-for-gem-installation-when-i-run-bundle-install)

So in my case:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-9.3/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-9.3
bundle install
```

And that took a day, well could have been worse

Answer (score 0):

So you know in the future, this wasn't an RVM issue. This was a bundler and gem command parameter passing issue. RVM wasn't involved at that stage.