# How to compile in set_single_row_mode method of pg GEM?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, amazon-redshift

I did `gem install pg` to install a Ruby GEM for PostgreSQL, but the installed `PG::Connection` class does not have `set_single_row_mode` method.

I found the following lines in `pg_connection.c`, which is a source file of the GEM.

```
#ifdef HAVE_PQSETSINGLEROWMODE
    rb_define_method(rb_cPGconn, "set_single_row_mode", pgconn_set_single_row_mode, 0);
#endif
```

It seems that C files of the GEM must be compiled with `-DHAVE_PQSETSINGLEROWMODE` option. However, I don't know how to pass `-DHAVE_PQSETSINGLEROWMODE` to the installation process of `gem install pg`.

Could anyone help me out?

```
// My environment.
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.20
```

--- Edited ---

Hmm. It seems that Single Row Mode is available only since version 9.2. I tried the following:

```
$ gem fetch pg
$ gem unpack pg-0.18.1.gem
$ cd pg-0.18.1
$ ruby ext/extconf.rb
$ vi extconf.h
    # Added '#define HAVE_PQSETSINGLEROWMODE 1'
$ make
```

but error messages like below were displayed.

```
ext/pg_result.c: In function ‘pgresult_stream_each’:
ext/pg_result.c:1109: error: ‘PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ext/pg_result.c:1109: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ext/pg_result.c:1109: error: for each function it appears in.)
ext/pg_result.c: In function ‘pgresult_stream_each_row’:
ext/pg_result.c:1172: error: ‘PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

It would be possible to update PostgreSQL libraries on the local machine to 9.2 or newer, but I'm afraid that it would be meaningless unless the server (Redshift) supports Single Row Mode. Does Redshift support it?

Comment: What version of Ruby and Postgres are you working with here?

Comment: I edited the question to add information about version numbers of `ruby` and `psql`. Does it help?

Comment: Postgres 8.4 is extremely old. Does this problem persist with newer versions like 9.3 or 9.4?

Comment: To be exact, I'm working on Amazon Redshift (http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/), which is a variant of PostgreSQL. It will take time for me to prepare PostgreSQL 9.3/9.4 to check whether this issue still persists...

Comment: Maybe the [advice given here applies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167829/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-for-gem-installation-when-i-run-bundle-install). I usually do everything I can to avoid having to do that because it's a pain to update things, you'll often forget the switches you had to add to make it work.